# App Engine: create object inside a transaction

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm writing a site on GAE-Java + Objectify which lets users create their own pages, with unique URL. I haven't been able to figure out a clear way to ensure that when two users try to claim the same url at the same time, only one user gets it.

This is what I'm trying to avoid:

- User 1 does a check - its available
- User 2 does a check - its available
- Meanwhile, User 1 creates page and stores it.
- User 2 creates a page and overwrites User 1.

Any ideas on how to solve this on GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just run your code in a [transaction](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Transactions)?  I don't see where the issue is.  Do you have a sample of something you've tried and had problems with?

Comment: No... I'm not really able to test this kind of scenario. I don't understand how it would work when user 1 and 2 are running in their own individual transactions.

Comment: Entity groups are involved even if you don't think they are.  Every entity is implicitly in a Entity Group even if you don't explicitly put it in one.  and any transaction can only involve entities in one entity group.

Answer (score 0):

Found a clearer explanation in the [python docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_or_insert):

> Attempts to get the entity of the model's kind with the given key name. If it exists, get_or_insert() simply returns it. If it doesn't exist, a new entity with the given kind, name, and parameters in kwds is created, stored, and returned.
>   The get and subsequent (possible) put are wrapped in a transaction to ensure atomicity. Ths means that get_or_insert() will never overwrite an existing entity, and will insert a new entity if and only if no entity with the given kind and name exists.
>   In other words, get_or_insert() is equivalent to this Python code:

```
def txn():
  entity = MyModel.get_by_key_name(key_name, parent=kwds.get('parent'))
  if entity is None:
    entity = MyModel(key_name=key_name, **kwds)
    entity.put()
  return entity

return db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```